# Where did the trait in man come from which causes him to deny the superiority of God?

Tags: nature-of-god, nature-of-man, evolution

Since man was created in the image of God, which I consider to be that God created man with those traits, common to God himself. The power to reason, and so on.

In that light I  find it difficult to accept that man is so egotistical as to deny an intelligence and power superior to himself.

The reasoning I use to make that Statement stems from the popularity of the theory of evolution, the lengths to which society will go in order to legitimize it.

Every time some different fossil is found there seems to be a concerted effort to somehow garner it as proof of Evolution. All the while ignoring that even in our lifetime some species have become extinct for Environmental reasons. And will some future generation (assuming there will be one) find fossil remains from some extinct species such as the dodo bird and proclaim it as proof of evolution.

If we being made in God's image have such pride as to believe that we are the pinnacle of intelligence are we not proclaiming ourselves at least equal to God.

It almost seems that if we deny the existence of God, we are proclaiming man is God or the most superior of all.

In my humble opinion that is the most dangerous sin of all, being the thing that caused Lucifer to be ejected from Heaven.

My question then is since no such attitude was apparent in Adam, did God create man with this egomania intentionally or was this part of the Knowledge of good and evil, which came from man's disobedience in the Garden of Eden?

Comment: Would any of the downvoters help Cecil out by explaining their reasons?

Comment: @Wikis Maybe I'm wrong, but the down votes only highlight my question.

Comment: I like this question, it helps people define faith.

Comment: @Onlyheisgood. apparently no one agrees with you since there are no up votes.

Comment: Understanding my type of faith is fearful, having faith that all is well regardless is easy. People tend to agree with what that they like.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above mention Eve. Eve created from Adam/Man. Man may think that is why the serpent fooled Eve.
But in Eve's defense, then God created an enmity between Eve and the serpent. Theoretically speaking,
the serpent/devil cannot fool Eve/Woman again.

Genesis 3:15 GOD'S WORD

> I will make you and the woman hostile toward each other. I will make
>   your descendants and her descendant hostile toward each other. He will
>   crush your head, and you will bruise his heel."

How big is the enmity? Why is my wife more spiritual than me?

> "All the reasonings of men are not worth one sentiment of women."
>   **Voltaire**

So, all that aside, all that is left is Man. The most egocentric thing on Earth. Fooled by satan.

> Chuck Norris doesn't do push ups. He pushes the world down.

Evolution vs Creation. Bill Nye vs Ken Ham. What I learned from that debate is that
Man likes to use science to predict results. That is great in it's sense. 
Bill Nye thanks to science for feeding 7 Billion people vs 1 Billion people before science.
This adds to Man's ego. As if [Matthew 6:31](http://biblehub.com/matthew/6-31.htm) and [Matthew 4:4](http://biblehub.com/matthew/4-4.htm) are not enough for the science Man.

As if Man must be in the same league as God.

You asked why. I don not know.

God said in Job 38:4 NLT

> Where were you when I laid the foundations of the earth? Tell me, if
>   you know so much.

Comment: Your last scripture would appear to answer the whole Question.

Comment: You might want to add Psalm 8- what is man that thou art mindful of him...

Answer (score 0):

**Where did the trait in man come from which causes him to deny the superiority of God?** It started with the fruit of the knowledge of good and evil. "You will not certainly die,” the serpent said to the woman. "For God knows that when you eat from it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and evil." (Gen 3:4-5). Now if this statement is true or not is for another discussion seeing as how the message came from the serpent. Eve certainly believed it regardless, and this shows her desire to be like God, and by choosing her own way instead of God's that can be measured as denying the superiority of God.

**Since man was created in the image of God, which I consider to be that God created man with those traits, common to God himself. The power to reason, and so on.** If you see it from God's point of view it makes sense. If you where all alone for eternity would you not want a friend? Yet what if your friend killed you? Then you would cease to exist so you would want your friend to be similar to you, but you would want to make sure that your friend wouldn't want to kill you. This would be a big point.

**In that light I find it difficult to accept that man is so egotistical as to deny an intelligence and power superior to himself.** This may not be so much as egotistism as is it was non-confrontationalism. Remember it was his wife that brought him the fruit. He would have had to deny his wife to obey God.

**The reasoning I use to make that Statement stems from the popularity of the theory of evolution, the lengths to which society will go in order to legitimize it.** I suggest watching the Genesis Code.

**Every time some different fossil is found there seems to be a concerted effort to somehow garner it as proof of Evolution. All the while ignoring that even in our lifetime some species have become extinct for Environmental reasons. And will some future generation (assuming there will be one) find fossil remains from some extinct species such as the dodo bird and proclaim it as proof of evolution.** I see evolution as the formulation of the word, for example a sentence uses previous words to build a concept. So it is as simple as when he said the words.

**If we being made in God's image have such pride as to believe that we are the pinnacle of intelligence are we not proclaiming ourselves at least equal to God.** Some people do indeed consider themselves equal if not greater the God.

**It almost seems that if we deny the existence of God, we are proclaiming man is God or the most superior of all.** This is what I call the Pyramid Theory.

**In my humble opinion that is the most dangerous sin of all, being the thing that caused Lucifer to be ejected from Heaven.** Possible.

**My question then is since no such attitude was apparent in Adam, did God create man with this egomania intentionally or was this part of the Knowledge of good and evil, which came from man's disobedience in the Garden of Eden?** See first the pride in the daily usage of the knowledge of good and evil. For pride is the fruit. By casting away pride, we eat only the fruits of the Spirit (Galatians 5:22-23). That is why we have been called to consider ourselves dead to pride (1 John 2:16). Otherwise we are cast into the fires of anger when we meet the Jesus (Isaiah 28:16). And out countenance falls, and our spirit pays the penalty that leads to death. For the flesh and the Spirit are against each other (Galatians 5:17). The fruits bear witness to the spirit (Matthew 7:15-20).

Therefore circumcise the inner flesh (casting away sexual immorality), the heart (love only the Father and care not for the world), and the Spirit (by casting away anger wrath and Jealousy) by the faith that God will fulfill the law (Matthew 5:17). For vengeance belongs to him (Romans 12:19).

Comment: My question does not ask about believing in God, my question is why does man consider himself so highly that he feels equal to God in hierarchy.

Comment: Man consider himself so highly that he feels equal to God in hierarchy when he doesn't trust God, instead he chooses the way the seems the best, that is why the answer is about believing in God.

Answer (score 0):

### Eve doubted the words of God

Doubting God's word is not the same as denying the superiority of God. You can still believe that God is superior than you but at the same time you can still doubt God's words and think that He is lying to you.

### Denying the existence of God

It is a popular understanding that the connection with God and man was lost after the fall of Adam, also known as "Spiritual Death". Man cannot see God face to face since then. God no longer visited men everyday at noon. God very rarely communicates with man, but only through few prophets and apostles whom God chose. Though man still have some inherent consciousness about the existence of God, man refuses to believe because man cannot see God, except those few who experienced the existence of God. We only believe what we can see, thus the saying "*Seeing is believing*". How can we believe something we cannot see? We tend to believe in Science more than God because we can see Science but we cannot see God.

> Man stops believing in the superiority of God when man can no longer
>   see God

### Blessed are those who have not seen and yet have believed

> Then Jesus told him, "Because you have seen me, you have believed;
>   blessed are those who have not seen and yet have believed." (John
>   20:29, NIV)

Comment: My question did not ask about believing in God, many people who believe in Evolution profess to believe there is a God. My question was why would any man who professes to believe there is a God, believe that he was the pinnacle of natural selection as Evolutionists do. True he is the pinnacle of creation, but even that is puny by comparison to the Creator. Robots are a marvelous invention, but they are no where near as marvelous as man is and God is even farther above man than man is above the robot.my point really is in the fact that God is as superior to man as man is to the robot.

Answer (score 0):

This question raises some issues that can best be addressed by more closely relating individual parts of the question with the assumptions that lead to the question part:

```
Since man was created in the image of God, which I consider to be that God created 
man with those traits, common to God himself... 
If we being made in God's image have such pride as to believe that we are the pinnacle 
of intelligence are we not proclaiming ourselves at least equal to God.
```

[Creation.com](http://creation.com/pinnacle-of-creation) does indeed make just this claim, whether or not we consider it egotistical:

> The Bible indicates, therefore, that man is a unique, spiritual being, **the pinnacle of creation**.

Apart from [Genesis 1:27](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Genesis&chapter=1&verse=27), there are no grounds for the belief that man is the pinnacle of creation, which is therefore apparently egotistical.

No one can deny that the people who support creation.com believe in God, but the question goes on to wrong-foot, on exactly the same grounds, those who do not believe in the existence of God:

```
Since man was created in the image of God... In that light I find it difficult to
accept that man is so egotistical as to deny an intelligence and power superior to himself.
It almost seems that if we deny the existence of God, we are proclaiming man is God
 or the most superior of all.
```

In dissecting the logic put forward by this question, it appears that man is egotistical whether he believes in the existence of God or does not believe. It need only be pointed out that those who do not believe in God, whether they believe in other gods or none at all, are by definition not proclaiming that man is God.

```
Did God create man with this egomania intentionally or was this part of the Knowledge 
of good and evil, which came from man's disobedience in the Garden of Eden?
```

If God made man in his own image ([Genesis 1:27](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Genesis&chapter=1&verse=27)) then we can not say God created man with this egomania intentionally. We can not say that this is part of the Knowledge of good and evil, which came from man's disobedience in the Garden of Eden, if the Bible tells us that Adam and Eve learnt a painful lesson because of their disobedience. It seems from the assumptions put forward in this question that man is predisposed to be egotistical, and that is reflected in both belief and non-belief.

The question also raises a somewhat unrelated issue of evolution, arguing *ad absurdum*:

```
The reasoning I use to make that Statement stems from the popularity of the theory 
of evolution, the lengths to which society will go in order to legitimize it.

Every time some different fossil is found there seems to be a concerted effort to 
somehow garner it as proof of Evolution. All the while ignoring that even in our 
lifetime some species have become extinct for Environmental reasons. And will some 
future generation (assuming there will be one) find fossil remains from some 
extinct species such as the dodo bird and proclaim it as proof of evolution.
```

The question does not stop to consider that the Theory of Evolution is popular because it is the best explanation for the observed facts. The extinction of the dodo does not, and can not, prove that evolution has occurred. Pope Francis, who is is not known as egotistical and is certainly a believer in the existence of God, [in a speech given at a Pontifical Academy of Sciences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Church_and_evolution#Pope_Francis), has declared his support of evolution as the scientific explanation of the origin of man.